# msg_name of a struct msghdr doesn't point to a struct sockaddr_in in socket_recvmsg of linux security module

Tags: c, linux, linux-kernel, network-programming, selinux

I use a security operation 'socket_recvmsg' in the Linux security module.

```
int (*socket_recvmsg) (struct socket *sock,struct msghdr *msg, int size, int flags)
```

Msg->msg_name is supposed to point to a struct sockaddr_in, which contains the sin_family, source port and source ip address. msg->msg_namelen indicates the size of data pointed by msg->msg_name. However, the msg->msg->namelen in my socket_recvmsg function is always 112, which is far larger than sizeof(struct sockaddr_in). So I guess msg->msg_name must point to some other data structure, rather than struct sockaddr_in. Does anyone know what data type the msg->msg_name in socket_recvmsg point to?

Also, the msg->msg_name in my sendmsg function always equals to sizeof(struct sockaddr_in), and I can get port and ip address from msg->msg_name in sendmsg function.

Answer (score 3):

The `msg_name` field of `struct msghdr` does not necessarily have to point to a `struct sockaddr_in`: it points to a generic socket address; the exact structure depends on the socket family: if it's an `AF_UNIX` socket, it points to a `struct sockaddr_un`, if it's `AF_INET`, it points to `struct sockaddr_in`, and if it's `AF_INET6` it points to `struct sockaddr_in6`. All of them share the `sa_family` field, which is also the first field, so you can cast `msg_name` to `struct sockaddr *`, read the `sa_family` field, and decide where to go from there.

Keep in mind that there may be other socket families implemented; Linux, for example, has `AF_APPLETALK`, `AF_X25`, and some others I don't remember right now.

> Also, the msg->msg_name in my sendmsg function always equals to
>   sizeof(struct sockaddr_in)

This is true as long as you're using `AF_INET` sockets, because ip addresses and port numbers have a fixed length. But the size argument is not always a statically known value. In UNIX sockets (local sockets), the size you pass is not `sizeof(struct sockaddr_un)`, but instead it is `offsetof(struct sockaddr_un, sa_data)+strlen(pathname)`, where `pathname` is the size of the path string in the filesystem where the socket handle lives.

Comment: Hi Filipe, thanks for your reply. Your explanation makes sense to me. I was doing udp and tcp stuff, so the packets should all be  AF_INET. However, in my socket_recvmsg function, the first 2 bytes pointed by msg_name  is always 0 (AF_UNSPEC), and the msg_namelen is 112 . So do you know what data type the msg_name is actually point to?

Comment: @ruofan I'm really not sure what exactly is this `socket_recvmsg()` function. Where did you find it? From what I could see, this is a PHP function, am I right? It may be the case that it's internally used by the PHP library and wraps things in another internal structure.

Comment: So `socket_recvmsg()` is a function defined in `linux/security.h`. It is part of linux security module. `socket_recvmsg()` will be called before the actual recvmsg system call. Developer can register a linux kernel module, and reimplement `socket_recvmsg()` in order to do some security or permission checking before the packet arrives to the `recvmsg' system call.

Comment: I think I found why the size is 112 when it receives a udp packet. At the stage my hook function socket_recvmsg() gets called, the struct msghdr has not been set up yet. So msg->msg_name is pointing to a struct sockaddr_un, and with size of 112.

Comment: @ruofan That's good to know. I actually had thought that *maybe* `msghdr` had not been set up by the time your function is called and so it may be the case that it was pointing to the largest possible address structure (to accomodate for any socket type). It makes sense, but it was only a suspicion. If you found a solution for your problem, you should post an answer and accept it. I will gladly upvote it!

Answer (score 0):

`socket_recvmsg` is a hook function in `security.h`. It provides permission checking for `recvmsg` call. However, the hook is a pre-op, which means the hook function occurs before the actual operation `recvmsg`. At the stage of socket_recvmsg, the `struct msg` has not been set up for any specific `sockaddr`.

I tested on centos 6.6. The `msg->msg_len` is 112 for udp socket, and is 128 for tcp packet at `socket_recvmsg`.